# How long should Hive insert take?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

How long should a simple Insert command take in hive? I'm finding the following command takes around 10 seconds every time. Any suggestions for optimizing the time? I know Hive may perform better creating new rows from existing tables, or from files saved in HDFS, but I'm trying to avoid this.

```
command = "INSERT INTO dataset VALUES (123, 'Name', 50, 155.5)"

with pyhs2.connect(host=host, authMechanism="PLAIN", user=username, password=password, database=database) as conn: 
     with conn.cursor() as cur:                                              
         cur.execute(command)
```

Comment: Hive has been designed for *massive batch processing* and the transaction processing is a new and awkward patch. So 10s per insert is rather good IMHO. Why did you choose Hive in the first place???

Comment: I am mainly using it for batch processing of large sets of data, but I also need to occasionally make small inserts. I was originally just creating CSV files locally, putting them to HDFS, then importing those into Hive, but wanted to avoid creating these temporary files, so I thought I would try the new INSERT command. I did discover that if I connect once and run a series of commands, large and small combined, I still get about a 10 second time, regardless of the size of the individual commands.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe with TEZ and a tweak of `tez.am.container.idle.release-timeout-min.millis` and `...-max...` you could have faster response times after the initial connection overhead.